# C# How to limit the score?

Tags: c#, if-statement

How to limit the score?
player & enemy score is incrementing everytime a player or enemy wins what i wanted to happen is whoever reach 3 points first will win.

```
int playerScore = 0;
int enemyScore = 0;
private void UpdateScore(bool playerWon)
{
  if (playerWon)
  {
    playerScore++;
    stateLabel.Text = "win";
    playerScoreLabel.Text = playerScore.ToString();
  }
  else
  {
    enemyScore++;
    stateLabel.Text = "lose";
    enemyScoreLabel.Text = playerScore.ToString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Do y ou know `if` statements? `if (playerScore >= 3  || enemyScore >= 3) { // Game Over }`

Comment: Well you clearly know how an if statement works - surely you can use your own logic to work out where to add the additional code

Comment: Then,after updating the scores, check if any of them have reached 3

Comment: Well, the simplest solution was to provide a method parameter that specifies which player has won. You don't need the `playerWon` paraneter because this method is used only if one of both players has won. You just need to know which player it was.

Answer (score 0):

I know that's not working, you need to modify it. Just to give you some impressions maybe.

```
 int playerScore = 0;
 int enemyScore = 0;
 List<Player> players = new List<Player>();

  private void UpdateScore(bool playerWon)
        {
                if (playerWon)
                {
                    players[Count].score++;
                    stateLabel.Text = "win";
                    playerScoreLabel.Text = playerScore.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    players[Count].score++;
                    stateLabel.Text = "lose";
                    enemyScoreLabel.Text = playerScore.ToString();
                }

                CheckPlayerWon();
           }

    private Player CheckPlayerWon()
    {
        foreach(Player play in players)
        {
            if(play.score >= 3)
            {
                // WON
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private class Player
    {
        string name = string.empty;
        int playerID = 0;
        int score = 0;

        Player()
        {
            //SETUP
        }
    }
```

Comment: You better should write a comment, instead of just voting it down. Why should we provide such a easy solution for someone? That's basic stuff here, nothing special. I just want to give impressions to do it at his own.

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach would be to do something like the following. This could be far more elegant, obviously.

```
int playerScore = 0;
int enemyScore = 0;
private GameState UpdateScore(bool playerWon)
{
    const int scoreToReach = 3;

    if (playerWon)
    {
        playerScore++;
        stateLabel.Text = "win";
        playerScoreLabel.Text = playerScore.ToString();

        if (playerScore == scoreToReach)
            return GameState.PlayerWon;
    }
    else
    {
        enemyScore++;
        stateLabel.Text = "lose";
        enemyScoreLabel.Text = playerScore.ToString();

        if (enemyScore == scoreToReach)
            return GameState.EnemyWon;
    }

    return GameState.GameInProgress;
}

public enum GameState
{
    GameInProgress,
    PlayerWon,
    EnemyWon
}
```